# Why don't plane seats have shoulder straps?

Tags: seats, seatbelts

Why don't seats on airliners have shoulder straps, like the seats in (European) coaches often do? Wouldn't a shoulder-strap be more effective than adopting the brace position, in the event of a crash-landing?

There's no definite answer in the other question. Speculation that the brace position may be safer than a restrained torso but unrestrained head. Speculation that seats may not be strong enough to usefully hold a shoulder strap.

I'd like to know whether the lap-strap is a "legacy" pre-dating automotive shoulder-strap inertia-lock mechanisms (retained for economic reasons?), or whether lap-straps are actually known to be a safer solution in an aircraft environment (without air-bags, with a seat in front).

Comment: Related: [Why did my business class seat have a three point shoulder harness?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47474/14897)

Comment: Perhaps it's because the main purpose of airplane seat belts is to keep passengers from bouncing around during turbulence, and a lap belt is sufficient for that?

Comment: Those European coaches only have shoulder straps on the first seat row. The rest has lap belts, just like airliners do.

Comment: I think the duplicate question covers this one. But to re-iterate, it's because the purpose of the seat belt is not to protect the human body from sudden deceleration like in a car. Therefore it is neither pre-dating modern road car seat belts for economic reason, nor because lap belts are safer. It is a different solution engineered to solve a different problem: keep passengers in their seats during turbulence. The belts on airplanes keep passengers from going *up* while belts in cars keep passengers from going *forward*.

Comment: @kevin I don't think that's right. The lap belt decelerates your lower body in a lateral deceleration, while the seat back in front of you yields and supports your upper body. Note brace position, where you pre-position your head on the seat, as well as the fact that bulkhead rows or premium seats with legroom in front have airbags or shoulder belts. In a car, there is no close, yielding, flat surface in front of you. Rather, there's a steering wheel or windshield.

Comment: @user71659 car rear-seat passengers have a seat in front that could be made flat and yielding. However, the shoulder-strap seat-belt is the usual safety measure. Same could be said of the front passenger seat were it not for the air-bag.