# Why are airline seat belts lap-only?

Tags: safety, commercial-aviation, seatbelts

On the flight that I was on today, one of the passengers near me asked this question. Why don’t airplanes use lap- and shoulder belts like cars do?

Comment: [Closely related](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/29211/62), maybe a dupe?

Comment: Related: [Why did my business class seat have a three point shoulder harness?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/47474/14897)

Comment: @Pondlife Yes, this is a duplicate. I did not see that question in my search. Thank you.